# Null pointer exception and Im not sure why

Tags: java, xml, file-io, nullpointerexception

This question is complicated so ill do my best to talk about everything clearly and if I need to elaborate anything or take anything irrelevent out of this post please tell me.  My program is used to read an XML file and print an array with 2 products that are the data revived from the XML file it 3 times adding in a 3rd element to the array after the array prints the first time and deleting it after the array prints the second time.  The program tells the user when it adds or removes this third element   This means the desired output is

```
Product list:
code of the first product   name of the first product       price of the first product
code of the second product   name of the second product     price of the second product

XML Tester has been added to the XML document 


Product list:
code of the first product   name of the first product       price of the first product
code of the second product   name of the second product     price of the second product
code of the XML tester       name of the XMl tester         price of the XML tester

XML tester has been deleted from the XML document.


Product list:
code of the first product   name of the first product       price of the first product
code of the second product   name of the second product     price of the second product
```

However after the first time I get a Null pointer Exception error in trying to print the products the second time with the new added tester

This occurs in line 67 of my code as follows In order to make it more obvious where the error occurs and make it clearer

```
p.setDescription(description);
```

The item my debugger said description is set to at this moment is "Murach's Beginning Java" and i'm not sure why this is a null pointer since this exact description worked the first time my program printed to the console

Here is what my program looks like With notes of things ive noticed while debugging the program in order to make this problem easier to help with

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.stream.*;  // StAX API

public class XMLTesterApp
{
    private static String productsFilename = "products.xml";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        **This first part the XML file contains two values and it prints both fine*****
        System.out.println("Products list:");
        ArrayList<Product> products = readProducts();
        printProducts(products);

        *** This part adds a tester line to the print out and this is the point the 
        *** null pointer exception error starts to happen This is used as a test to
        *** make sure my file writer method is working by an instructor and the program
        ***  is supposed to fail here if I am doing something wrong but I can't figure
        ***  out what im doing wrong ************************
        Product p1 = new Product("test", "XML Tester", 77.77);
        products.add(p1);
        writeProducts(products);
        System.out.println("XML Tester has been added to the XML document.\n");


        System.out.println("Products list:");
        products = readProducts();
        printProducts(products);


        products.remove(2);
        writeProducts(products);
        System.out.println("XML Tester has been deleted from the XML document.\n");


        System.out.println("Products list:");
        products = readProducts();
        printProducts(products);

    }

   private static ArrayList<Product> readProducts()
{
    ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
    Product p = null;
    XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
    try
    {
        //create a stream reader object
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("products.xml");
        XMLStreamReader reader = inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(fileReader);
        //read XML file
        while (reader.hasNext())
        {
          int eventType = reader.getEventType();
          switch (eventType)
          {
               case  XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT :
                  String elementName = reader.getLocalName();
                  //get the product and its code
                  if (elementName.equals("Product"))
                  {
                     p = new Product();
                     String code = reader.getAttributeValue(0);
                     p.setCode(code);
                  }   
                  // get the product description
                  if (elementName.equals("Description"))
                  {
                     String description = reader.getElementText();
                     ************Error occurs on the line under this note*************
                     p.setDescription(description);

                  }    
                  // get the product price
                  if (elementName.equals("Price")) 
                  {

                      String priceS = reader.getElementText();
                      double price = Double.parseDouble(priceS);
                      **** As I test I removed the set descirption line and then 
                           this line returned the same error that that line
                           did*********************************************
                      p.setPrice(price);
                  }    
                  break;
               case XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT :
                  elementName = reader.getLocalName();
                  if(elementName.equals("Product"))
                  {
                    products.add(p);  
                  }    
                  break; 
              }
         reader.next();
        }    
    }
    catch (IOException | XMLStreamException e)
    {
      System.out.println(e); 
    }    
     return products;
    }

    private static void writeProducts(ArrayList<Product> products)
    {
      XMLOutputFactory outputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
        try
        {
            //create a stream reader object
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("products.xml");
            XMLStreamWriter writer = outputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(fileWriter);
            //write to the XML file
            writer.writeStartDocument("1.0");
            writer.writeStartElement("Products");
            for (Product p : products)
            {
                writer.writeStartElement("Prodcut");
                writer.writeAttribute("Code", p.getCode()) ;
                writer.writeStartElement("Description");  
                writer.writeCharacters(p.getDescription());
                writer.writeEndElement();
                writer.writeStartElement("Price");
                double price = p.getPrice();
                writer.writeCharacters(Double.toString(price));
                writer.writeEndElement();
                writer.writeEndElement();
            }
            writer.writeEndElement();
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        }  
        catch (IOException | XMLStreamException e)
        {
           System.out.println("e"); 
        }
    }

    private static void printProducts(ArrayList<Product> products)
    {
        for (Product p : products)
        {
            printProduct(p);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    private static void printProduct(Product p)
    {
        String productString =
            StringUtils.padWithSpaces(p.getCode(), 8) +
            StringUtils.padWithSpaces(p.getDescription(), 44) +
            p.getFormattedPrice();

        System.out.println(productString);
    }
}
```

This is for a class and I spent a few hours both reviewing my code and my textbook but can't figure out what Im doing wrong with my code.

Comment: If it's a null-pointer-exception on line 67, it would be 'p' which is null, not description. It's fine (but not always desirable) to pass around a variable containing null, but you can't call a method on a null object

Comment: Thinking about it I undestand that im trying to set p to the description but that's not happening so it results in a null. Why does p work the first run through then and whats the best way to fix the issue cause by the loop running more than once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the cause is:

```
  writer.writeStartElement("Prodcut");
```

You are writing out an element `<Prodcut>` but then later on you try to process the element . Your parsing code never finds `<Product>` so never goes into the part of your switch statement that begins:

```
 if (elementName.equals("Product"))
```

and so you never create a product object p. This causes a null pointer exception when you try to setDescription on p.

You should be able to spot this using your debugger.

Comment: Thanks this is really insightful but im still not sure on why my code never finds Product and how to remedy it I think that you mean product doesn't exist when my switch statement is looking for it but if I just wrote it why can't the program find it?

Comment: You've mis-spelt "Product" when you write-out the XML. Prodcut != Product :-)

Comment: Thanks :) I just spent the last 2.5 hours trying to find a way to fix this and I misplace a u figures.  Oh well not a total loss I understand a lot more about how my code works now my book tends to give examples of what works but not explain how it works and is more like a reference book where you can find sample code but not much about why it works like it does so thanks for the insight